# How do I change the series names in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to change the series name of each plot, but I don't know how to. I tried to find on Google and what it recommends is `Series.Name = ""`, but it is not working.

[image: Excel]

```
Sub Profit_Graph()

     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Dim rng As Range
     Dim objChrt As ChartObject
     Dim chrt As Chart

     Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graph")

     With ws
         Set rng = .Range("A3:A14,B3:D14")
         .Shapes.AddChart
         Set objChrt = .ChartObjects(.ChartObjects.Count)
         Set chrt = objChrt.Chart

         With chrt
            .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
            .SetSourceData Source:=rng
         End With

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Nested `With`'s can behave unpredicatably and are best to avoid.

Comment: @ashleedawg I've never seen nested `With` blocks behave unpredictably. I've seen them confuse readers by sadly increasing the cognitive load of a procedure, thus making it easier to introduce bugs, but AFAICT they do nothing more than what they're told. Got a link or an example?

Comment: @Mat'sMug -- okay, I'll rephrase: Nested `With` blocks behave exactly as they are supposed to, but perhaps not as users would expect.  When having a problem, simplify your code.

Comment: Tips on [Nested Control Structures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/control-flow/nested-control-structures).

Comment: @ashleedawg hey that's a good link to keep around, for all the "Block If without End If" & similar questions that get asked =)